# Where are these graffiti spots by the water in Brink Terminal?

Tags: bomb-rush-cyberfunk

In Brink Terminal there are 3 graffiti spots marked on my map near a small inlet of water that overlooks Pyramid Island. I've visited these spots but I can't find anywhere to spray.

How do I reach these graffiti spots by the water in Brink Terminal?

[image: Overlooking the water with phone showing 3 graffiti spots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drain the water to reach those graffiti spots.

Talk to an NPC named Mesh on the bridge. (You may need to talk to Mesh in other locations before he moves to the bridge). Mesh will tell you you can drain the water using a control terminal. Head past the Oldhead (requires 140 rep) and towards the dock. Grind up a lamppost and wallride across a billboard. Look for a rail behind a fence on the side of the bulding and grind up it. Finally tag the control panel to drain the water. You will now be able to reach the graffiti spots.

Note: If the tag spot doesn't appear by the control panel, make sure you talked to Mesh on the bridge first.